# Can't replace UTF-8 character with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I have a string with the UTF-8 character `↵`. To my understanding, if you want to replace a UTF-8 character in a string, you specify the character with its hexadecimal representation, like so:

```
var string = "↵↵↵Middle↵↵↵";
console.log("Match? " + /\u21b5/.test("↵"));
console.log(string);
string = string.replace("/\u21b5/g", "");
console.log(string);
```

It is a match, but the replace is not working. What am I missing?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGfgv/1257/)

Comment: FYI: That's a unicode character (more precisely, a unicode code point), UTF-8 is just one possible encoding. If UTF-8 was used, it would be represented by the bytes `E2 86 B5`, but JavaScript uses USC-2 where this character is the 16 bit word `21B5`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a string not a regex

```
string = string.replace(/\u21b5/g, "");
```

Comment: *Palm meets face*
Thank you aduch.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
string = string.replace("/\u21b5/", "");
```

with

```
string = string.replace(/\u21b5/g, "");
```

Comment: *Flips table*
Thank you Fen1kz.